# How to make a div fill the remaning vertical space using css

Tags: css, html

I am attempting to make a standard website layout with a *header*, a *navigation bar* a body (on the right of the *navigation bar*) and a *footer*.

Now I have so far done this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            .header {
                float: top;
                width: 100%;
                height: 75px;
            }

            .navbar {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                height: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height:100%;
                overflow: scroll;
            }

            .body {
                float: right;
                width: 80%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height:100%;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
            .footer {
                float: bottom;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"> Header </div>
        <div class="navbar"> Nav Bar </div>
        <div class="body"> Body </div>
        <div class="footer"> Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

which produces this:

[image]

Now if we check the CSS:

```
.navbar {

    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.body {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

As you can see I have tried to set the *height* and *min-height* of both the body and *nav bar* to fill the remaining vertical space i.e:

[image]

Yet it doesnt affect it. However if I do `height: 500px` it resizes like expected (of course this now wont be very good practice as different screen sizes etc would show a different portion or view of the page):

[image]

So basically I am asking how would I be able to make the `divs` fill the vertical space that's left over without using some hard-coded value i.e `100px` rather I would want to do it in percentages thus the page will look the same on all browsers

Comment: you can use `display:table-cell`, but it won't support crappy IE 7 or less. Otherwise the dreaded `<table>` is a possible replacement to the divs. It's compatibility vs semantics.

Comment: @TheBronx Im kind cranky in HTML to be honest and I have searched but I cant find exactly what do to. another question says JQuery but I dont want to add more dependency (as I am doing XHTML and PHP)...

Comment: @AramKocharyan I see well Im aiming for compatibility hence the divs... but I just cant find any solution for a problem which I thought would be solved by `height:100%`?!?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp well, the real answer is "you can't fill the remaining vertical space with CSS". That's why you probably won't find a good solution. You will find javascript hacks and weird css combinations that try solve part of the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this code to your body,html:

```
body,html{
  height:100%;
}
```

and make your navbar `<div id="navbar">` instead of `<div class="navbar">`
then add height: 100%; to your navbar

```
#navbar{
  height:100%
// rest of your code
}
```

Same to your content
call it something like content, because body is already used.

```
#content{
  height:100%
// rest of your code
}
```

now all the divs will have a height of 100% so the full browser height.

EDIT: your full code would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            html, body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #header {
                width: 100%;
                height: 75px;
            }

            #navbar {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height:100%;
                overflow: scroll;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                width: 80%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height:100%;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
            #footer {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"> Header </div>
        <div id="navbar"> Nav Bar </div>
        <div id="content"> Body </div>
        <div id="footer"> Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried adding the changes but its not working my output goes haywire :(

Comment: OMW thanks man that helped so much thanks alot +1. Just one more question did I do a mistake by naming a `div` *body* and thus it clashed with the css `body,html` keyword because I see you changed the name to of body to `content` and added the `body,html` ?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp `body` and `.body` are different, but for semantics it makes sense to avoid duplicating the tag name as a class name.

Comment: @AramKocharyan +1 thanks alot Im actually learning PHP but its sending me on a crash course of CSS and HTML again :P

Comment: I've noticed that if you set HTML to height:100% inside IFRAMEs, javascript doesn't read the scrollheight correctly

Comment: And what if you set it to height:auto; min-height: 100%;?

Comment: There is no such thing as float: top and float: bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning for each content block (header, footer, sideber, body), and for the body and nav-bar divs, set both top and bottom position properties, rather than specifying the height property. This will force them to fill the remaining viewport height.

[More detail here](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions)

...and for supporting IE5 and IE6, [here's an improved version](http://www.dokma.dk/kongknabe/frameset_layout.html) using only CSS (no javascript).

Comment: It should be noted this answer only works if your header and footer are a static size, due to the  fact that you use absolute positioning.  If you wanted to accomplish the same thing using variable height header and footer, this method would not work.  You would need to modify the top and bottom values using javascript.