# Footer div does not respect CSS height or min-height

Tags: css, html

Okay so I asked a question earlier on:

[How to make a div fill the remaning vertical space using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923019/how-to-make-a-div-fill-the-remaning-vertical-space-using-css)

got an answer which Ive now been playing around with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            html, body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #header {
                float: top;
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: green;
            }

            #navbar {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                width: 80%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #footer {
                float: bottom;
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"> Header </div>
        <div id="navbar"> Nav Bar </div>
        <div id="content"> Body </div>
        <div id="footer"> Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now ultimatley Id want to achieve this:

[image]

in which it covers 100% of the screen but I can choose how those percentages are spread i.e:

```
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    float: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: green;
}

#navbar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#footer {
    float: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

As you can html and body have a height of 100% thus filling the screen. The header has a height percentage of 15% the nav bar and body have a percentage of 70% and the footer 15% which in total would make up the 100% of the visible screen...

Now everything seems fine except for my footer:

```
#footer {
    float: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

if I remove `height: 15%` then I can see my background color of yellow:

[image]

if I dont its some greyish color. and looks to take up about 20% of the screen:

[image]

So basically how would I get my divs to take up the correct height percentage I assigned them?

I hope Im making sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wow new element float: bottom; in your code ...

Comment: @RohitAzad hahaha still learning I thought it would be logical :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't float to top or bottom. That doesn't exist. So you have to remove that from your header and footer.

And clear the footer by doing:

```
footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that there is no:

```
float:top;
```

or

```
float:bottom;
```

What you need to do is make them both `float:left;`

here is a copy and paste of your code with the update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            html, body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #header {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: green;
            }

            #navbar {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                width: 80%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #footer {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"> Header </div>
        <div id="navbar"> Nav Bar </div>
        <div id="content"> Body </div>
        <div id="footer"> Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```