# How to use div tags to create table-like layout for html 5

Tags: css, html

I want to structure a html 5 page to use the available height of the browser window but not its width. I want to contain header, sidebar, footer and contents <div> tags inside a container <div> tag (or maybe nested container <div> tags) with fixed width.

I have searched the web extensively but no response actually worked.

The layout should be as displayed in the image:

[Layout image](http://www.ancientlocations.net/img/screenlayout.png)

I am adding no <style> suggestion here, not to provoke wrong answers.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works mate. Try writing the HTML and CSS. If you hit the wall with any specific issue, post about it here and you would get better responses/help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/UsWhQ/)

So, basically: I did it to improve myself. I dont think its good for you to just copy the entire thing.
read it, and try to make one from scratch.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="Page">
        <div id="SideBar"></div>
        <div id="Content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

#Container
{
    width: 70%; /* or: any fixed width that fits you */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: white;
}

#Header
{
    height: 75px; /* or: any fixed height that fits you */
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
#Page
{
    height: calc(100% - 125px); /* 100% - (Header.height + Footer.height) */
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}
#SideBar
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%; /* or: any fixed width that fits you */
}
#Content
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

#Footer
{
    height: 50px; /* or: any fixed height that fits you */
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. That seems to work. I had previously tried to adapt the responses from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923019/how-to-make-a-div-fill-the-remaning-vertical-space-using-css) but it did not work.